# Allow users to see own content only

Tags: views, users

I have two content types, `provider` and `products`.

The `providers` is a list of titles filtered by logged in user (each user can only see the providers he enterd). By clicking the `provider` the user is taken to a page that contains a table with all the provider products.

the `provider` and the `products` content type are linked via a unite content field using contextual filter (the mutual field called `lpid`).

In the products page the path is `provider/%/products` while the wildcard represents the lpid field.

Everything works great, what I am trying to do is to **prevent** from users to see other users content.

Is there a way to pass the wildcard via $_POST so the user will not be able manualy change the url?

TNX

Answer (score 1):

"Allow users to see own content only", You can achieve this using contextual filter and relationships in advance settings in views module, Given by you already set the contextual filter set filter to login user,

1.) In Advanced settings add field Content:author in relationships.

2.) Then in Contextual Filters add User: Uid and choose provide default value and set Provide default value Type User ID from logged in user.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your detailed answer, I did what you suggested in the `provider` content type, what I was asking is if there is a way to show the `products` items  to the users who inserted the `provider`. for example: one of my provider is `shoes store`.  the id of the `shoes store` is `227` in that provider i have products, the products are inserted by an external form and inserted as `products` content type items. now,  when i click the `shoes store` i am redirected to `provider/227/products` there i see all the products related. the problem is that if I write a different id in the...

Comment: ...URL  let's say `228` i wiil see all the products belong to the 228 provider which was created by other user. is there a way to prevent that? lets say pass the id variable in $_POST method?

Comment: can you provide current settings of your views so that I can use that as a reference? I will update my answer base on your current settings

Comment: also the id of the provider is that the user id of the provider?

Comment: [THIS IS THE PROVIDER VIEW](http://nimb.ws/nm1WYg)  .       [THIS IS THE PRODUCTS VIEW](http://nimb.ws/usT3bN)

Comment: the `unique` in `provider` equals` lpid` in `products`

Comment: I see have you tried to add relationships in product view to content:Content Author and also set the uid in contextual filter? and set it Provide default value Type User ID from logged in user.

Comment: I tried that in provider to product. exactley ass you suggested

Comment: is there a way to pass the id var in $_POST? so it will not be visieble?